# auth/network-request-failed error while signing in on Javascript app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Sign in and sign up sometimes works, but maximum time it gives the following error. But I'm able perform other firebase operations.

Error

```
{code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
```

Javascript code for sign in,

```
$("#signup_btn").click(function(){
  var username = document.getElementById("signup-username").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("signup-email").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("signup-name").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("signup-password").value;


if ($('#signup_btn').text()=="Sign Up") {


} else {

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {

}).catch(function(error) {
    var errorMessage = error.message;


        alert(errorMessage);

});

}

});
```

also Firebase SDK is up-to-date.

Thanx for the help...

Comment: What environment is this? Browser? Cordova app?